# How to Show Snackbar with the Result of Future Http Post?

Tags: flutter, dart, return, http-post, future

I'm trying to get a "File was uploaded." string back from a successful Future HTTP post request so that I can create a `SnackBar` but all I get back from the return is `null`. Here's the button which calls the `Future`;

```
IconButton(

    icon: Icon(TriangleAll.upload_3, ),

    onPressed: () async {

    replyresult = await uploadReply(
    filepath: _current.path);
)

 if (replyresult != null){

 print(replyresult);

    }
  }
)
```

And here's the code for the future;

```
Future<String> uploadReply(    

    }) async {

  final serverurl = "http://example.com/example.php";
  final filepath = "examplefilepath";
  String serverResponse;

  var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(serverurl));

  var multiPartFile = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath("audio", filepath,
      contentType: MediaType("audio", "mp4"));
      request.files.add(multiPartFile);
      request.send().then((result) async {

    http.Response.fromStream(result).then((response) {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        serverResponse = response.body;
        print(serverResponse);
        return serverResponse ;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I'm trying to use the `replyresult` variable to create the `snackbar` upon a successful 200 server response. I know the post is successful as I can see the correct printed `serverResponse`in the console.

I've tried to simply do;

```
return response.body ;
```

But I'm still getting null at the `replyresult` variable.

Comment: Its because you are using streams, just use simple http call or use package dio

Comment: `.then()` and `await` do no do the same things. Please do not mix them if you are not 100% sure what you are doing. For starters, `await` all your `Future`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked.

```
 var multiPartFile = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath("audio", filepath,
 contentType: MediaType("audio", "mp4"));
  request.files.add(multiPartFile);

  final response = await http.Response.fromStream(await request.send());
  String serverResponse;

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    String serverResponse = response.body;
    print(serverResponse);
    return serverResponse;
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

because the method returns before the response arrives in `Future`, do this

```
var response = await http.Response.fromStream(result);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        serverResponse = response.body;
        print(serverResponse);
        return serverResponse ;
} else return '';
```

or a single `await` ahead of the Future.

Comment: (result) is underlined red in Android Studio. Was I supposed to replace http.Response.fromStream(result).then((response)... with the above code?

Comment: yes exactly, look into the `Future(async await )` rather than hoping for the `Promise` ;)